# Cakephp Ajax, Using Js Helper to get value of a text field

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

guys this the code I am using to make a ajax request, its not the complete code just relevant stuff

```
<div class="container whiteFont">
    <label>New Tag</label>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('tagValue'); ?>

<input id="tag-button" type="button" value="Add Tag"/>
    <div id=tag></div>
<?php
    //on button click sands request to controller and displays response data in chosen field
    $this->Js->get('#tag-button')->event(
        'click',
        $this->Js->request(
            array('controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'add',(Here need help),$this->Form->value('Post.id')),
            array(
                'update' => '#tag',
                'async' => true,
            )
        )
    );
    ?>
```

Now the problem is, my actions takes in two parameters.
I can set the second one which is Post.id 
but I am not able to get the value of text field which has id of 'tagValue'.
I have tried using just html input fields as well. 
When I try to use Js->get here it doesnt work as well.
help me out please. 
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
 $this->Js->get('#tag-button')->event(
        'click',
        $this->Js->request(
        array('controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'add',(Here need help),$this->Form->value('Post.id')),
        array(
            'update' => '#tag',
            'async' => true,
            'dataExpression'=>true,
            'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
                'Post.id' => 1
            ))
```

use dataExpression and data to send parameters.

For more info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

Answer (score -1):

Proper way to get all your form parameters passed:

```
    $this->Js->get('#tag-button')->event(
    'click',
    $this->Js->request(
    array('controller' => 'tags', 'action' => 'add',(Here need help),$this->Form->value('Post.id')),
    array(
        'update' => '#tag',
        'async' => true,
        'dataExpression'=>true,
         'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
         'isForm' => true,
         'inline' => true
          ))
        ))
```